# Angular js $parse does not work

Tags: angularjs-directive, typescript

I have written a directive by using typescript. here is my directive below.

```
   'use strict';

    module App.Directives {

    interface IPageModal extends ng.IDirective {
    }

    interface IPageModalScope extends ng.IScope {

    }

    class PageModal implements IPageModal {
        static directiveId: string = 'pageModal';
        restrict: string = "A";

        constructor(private $parse: ng.IParseService) {

        }

        link = (scope: IPageModalScope, element, attrs) => {

            element.click((event) => {
                event.preventDefault();

                var options = {
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false
                };

                event.openModal = function () {
                    $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal(options);
                };
                event.showModal = function () {
                    $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal('show');
                };
                event.closeModal = function () {
                    $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal('hide');
                };
                var fn = this.$parse(attrs['pageModal']);
                fn(scope, { $event: event });
            });
        }
    }

    //References angular app
    app.directive(PageModal.directiveId, ['$parse', $parse => new PageModal($parse)]);
}
```

Use in HTML

```
<button class="btn blue-grey-900" target-modal="emplpyeeViewModal" page-modal="vm.addEmployee($event)">
    <i class="icon-plus  m-b-xs"></i>
</button>
```

Use in Controller

```
addEmployee($event) {
    $event.openModal();
};
```

This line does not work. `var fn = this.$parse(attrs['pageModal']);` . I can not understand what is wrong. The error is

> this.$parse is undefined.
>   and Service is called two times

Comment: this syntax `['$parse', ($parse) => new PageModal($parse)]` looks really awkward. Angular already forces you to make the funky array injection, you create the class with a property of injected service, and additionally you make it 2 times more: `($parse) => new PageModal($parse)`. What if you will have 10 services injected? 40 times listing same names?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite trivial: your `this` is not your class'es scope because the `function openmodal(event) {` defines its own.

Declare the function on a class level or use arrow function instead, e.g.

```
link = (scope: IPageModalScope, element, attrs) => {
    element.click((event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        var options = {
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        };

        event.openModal = function () {
            $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal(options);
        };
        event.showModal = function () {
            $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal('show');
        };
        event.closeModal = function () {
            $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal('hide');
        };
        var fn = this.$parse(attrs['pageModal']);//does not work here
        fn(scope, { $event: event });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, here new problem, Link function is called two times